# julia object in python class init

Tags: python, django, django-views, julia

I want to call a julia script out of my python code. No problem with pyjulia, but if I design it as a class there is a problem. I want to initialize julia and include a script in the init function. Below a example how I did is, I can't use self.jul in the funtion. it throws an error because self.jul has no function "myJulFuntion".  And I'm sure it is inside the julia script, because if I move the stuff from **init** to callJulFunc and call jl.myJulFuntion(params) it works.

Any ideas?

The problem is,

```
import julia
julia.Julia()
from julia import Main as jl


class juliaStuff:
    def __init__(self):
        self.jul = jl
        jl.include("my-julia-script.jl")
     # or as alternative try
        self.jul.include("my-julia-script.jl")

    def callJulFunc(self, params ):
        return self.jul.myJulFuntion(params)
```

Edit: I adjustet my code.  Now it crashes without an error at jl.include("my-julia-script.jl") or the alternative line.

@Hugo Trentesaux: In your code isn't a julia.Julia() init. without this it even doesn't work for me

My python version is 3.8.5
and julia is at 1.5.2

Edit 2: My problem is, that I'm using this in a Django Framework. Running a short example of this code is fine, but implementing it as a call from a views.py let's the django process crash after the include in the init. Just importing Main as jl and calling julia in a function is not a problem.

so in my views.py I added this:

```
# at the top of the file
import juliaStuff as ju

# in a function
jul= ju.juliaStuff()
jul_res = jul.callJulFunc(params)
```

Comment: Why do you assign `self.jul` twice? I don't know Julia at all, but this at least looks odd.

Comment: Can you clarify what you are even trying to do? Just from a Python design standpoint, treating ``jl`` as a black box, this looks very much wrong. As ``jl`` appears to be a global object, assigning it as the attribute ``self.jul`` is misleading – the class should just use the global ``jl``. Similarly, if ``jl.include("my-julia-script.jl")`` throws an error inside ``juliaStuff.__init__``, it will *also* throw an error outside of it. It appears that a [mcve] would not include the class at all; it should very likely include minimal Julia code, though.

Answer (score 2):

Try to move your julia import out of the class constructor and do not set `self.jul` as the output of `jl.include`:

```
# in script.jl
function hello()
 return "hello"
end
```

```py
# in code.py
import julia
julia.Julia()
from julia import Main as jl

class juliaStuff:
    def __init__(self):
        self.jul = jl
        jl.include("script.jl")

    def callJulFunc(self):
        return self.jul.hello()

obj = juliaStuff()

print(obj.callJulFunc())
```

Calling the python code prints "hello" in the terminal.

Comment: Please give more details of what does not work, because the code I show does work for me. Provide a minimum (not) working example including your julia script.

Comment: hugo, thanks for the suggestion, I edited the question and added more content what I'm doing. Your code runs fine, but not in Django.

Comment: What do you really want to do? It seems that we are falling into an [xyz problem](http://xyproblem.info/). I'm comfortable with Django too and I do not see how you're planning to use it.

Comment: can you please try to call your code.py from a django view? e.g. by just clicking a button. in this case I guess you will see the same problem as I do.